# Browser can not longer see saved CSS

Tags: html, css, twig

So I was working on a page for the last week, every time when I end my job I save my files and close VSCode. Today I came back, opened everything and started writing. After a while I noticed that my rules in CSS did not came up in the page. I thought I did something wrong, so I tried different methods but nothing worked. Then I just opened the CSS in browser with F12 to check if something is off and I saw that it had the last weeks saved CSS. I closed everything, tried again, but nothing. The file is saved in local, I can see when it was changed, but browser still gets to see the last week's save. The link in HTML is right, never changed, the files are in correct folders, all is good. I'm working with WordPress and Twig atm, if this can help somehow.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{site.theme.link}}/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

That's the link I used til now, it worked perfectly, paths never changed.

I'm sorry that I can't provide anything more but I can't really know what to show, like I changed nothing and it just stop working.

Thank you in advance for the time you'll take to help!

Comment: Have you tried deleting browser cache? Or reinstall browser?

Comment: @gpl I did clear the whole history, everything included, didn't changed. It's like that at Firefox but in Chrome it works. Should I reinstall the whole browser?

Comment: Just do a hard refresh next time `Ctrl` + `F5` or `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `R`

Comment: Many times I experienced hard refresh not works :( but as an option try it also

Comment: You can always disable cache within the developer tools to avoid this as well, see [here](https://nicholasbering.ca/tools/2016/10/09/devtools-disable-caching/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to reinstall Mozilla Firefox. Follow these steps:

- Backup your bookmarks (if you have any).
- Take a screenshot of Add-ons page. It will help you to find and reinstall them.
- Uninstall Firefox.

After uninstalling Firefox **remove these folders**:

`C:\Users\[your-user-name]\AppData\Local\Mozilla`

`C:\Users\[your-user-name]\AppData\LocalLow\Mozilla` and

`C:\Users\[your-user-name]\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla`.

If you have installed add-ons before uninstalling try this option:

`Menu` -> `Help` -> `Restart with Add-ons Disabled`

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a caching issue?

Try opening dev tools and then right clicking the refresh button.
It will give you an option to clear cache and hard refresh.
(Assuming your using chrome)

If that's the issue and you don't want to deal with it again, then you could consider appending a cachebuster to your css url.

The easiest way to do that would be something like
{{site.theme.link}}/styles.css?r={{ random(1, 1000) }}

Keep in mind that in production, that's going to slow down delivery though (just a little bit, css files usually aren't that large) because it's going to invalidate the browser cache each time the site loads.

Comment: I use Firefox, I reinstalled it and it got fixed for now. In Chrome worked perfectly. The thing that I'm afraid of its the possibility of this happening in a user's browser. Should I believe it was just a fluke?

Comment: There's options in firefox for disabling your cache while dev tools are open.  CSS and JS is cached by browsers, It's very common for clients to not immediately see css changes without some sort of cachebusting in place.

Comment: Without checking each thing in the above answer one at a time, I'm not sure what to tell you to believe.